# Tying to show that the weighted error equal 1/2 using adaboost?

Tags: machine-learning

Consider an ensemble classifier constructed by T rounds of AdaBoost on N training examples.
\begin{align} H(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{t= 1}^{T} \alpha_{t} h_{t}(\mathbf{x}) \end{align}

The next classifier: $h_{T+1}$ is added to the ensemble, by minimizing the training error weighted by $W_{1}^{T}$ ... $W_{N}^{T}$. For the question, I am trying to figure out how to show that $$\epsilon_{T + 1}$$ (the training error of $h_{T+1}$) weighted by the updated weights $W_{1}^{T+1}$ ... $W_{N}^{T+1}$ equals $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is Adaboost ?

Comment: Please add details on the definition of $h_t$ and the weight updates

Comment: @ClaudioMoneo $h_{t}$ is just a single weak classifier chosen for a specific t, which is a round of the adaboost. $H_(x)$ is the combination of all the weak classifiers used for the total rounds (T) that Adaboost is implemented: $H_\mathbf(x) = \alpha_{1} h_{1}\mathbf(x) + ... + \alpha_{T} h_{T}\mathbf(x)$

Comment: @JeanMarie Adaboost is a type of boosting algorithm.